# UIViewController: White space between UITableView and UIToolbar

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, scrollbar, uitoolbar

I have a `UIViewController` (included in a `UINavigationController`) with a `UITableView` and a `UIToolbar`. Now when I'm scrolling my view, there is always a white space (marked red in the picture) between the end of the tableView and the toolbar. Also the scrollbar stops at this point.

I've tried to uncheck `Adjust Scroll View Insets` in storyboard, but then the top of my tableView doesn't fit on the view.

Cann anybody help me to fix that issue?

[image]

EDIT:

I'm using `Auto Layout` and my storyboard configuration for the viewController looks like the following. In the previous viewController I'm using a `UITabBar` through a `UINavigationController`.

[image]

Comment: Did you use auto layout? Im guessing this is a layout issue. Can you give more details as to what you did in the mainstoryboard? Would help people understand better what the problem is and what you did until that point.

Comment: Please see my edited post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround for that problem:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()    
   tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -50, 0)
   tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = tableView.contentInset
}
```